# Is it possible to expose the contents of application.properties as key/value pairs in env inside the container?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, configmap

I have defined application properties files in a config dir. Config dir is on the below structure.

```
config
  application.properties
  application-test.properties
  application-dev.properties
  application-prod.properties
```

I have defined configmap as below

```
{{ range $path, $bytes := .Files.Glob "config/*" }}
  {{ base $path }}: '{{- $.Files.Get $path | nindent 2 | upper | replace "." "_" }}'
  {{- end }}
```

We are consuming the ConfigMap via environment variables in a running container using the envFrom property. (This in my deployment yaml file)

```
spec:
   containers:
   - envFrom:
     - configMapRef:
         name: nginx-configmap
```

Post running `helm install`, I see that configmap is generated.

```
kubectl describe cm sample-configmap
Data
====
----
 SERVER_PORT = 8080 SERVER_NAME = LOCALHOST SERVER_GREETING = GREETING-SERVICE 
----
```

In configmap,  the contents are not generated as single string instead of key/value pair.

Even, inside the container, the values are not stored as key/value pair. they are stored as string.

```
kubectl exec -it <pod> sh
/data # env | grep application.properties
application.properties= SERVER_PORT = 8080 SERVER_NAME = LOCALHOST SERVER_GREETING = GREETING-SERVICE SAMPLE_GROUPA_PARAM1 = VALUE1BASE SAMPLE_GROUPA_PARAM2 = VALUE2BASE SAMPLE_HIGHERPARAM = VALUEHIGHERBASE
/data # echo $application.properties
.properties
/data # echo $SERVER_PORT
```

I have also tried

```
data:
  {{- (.Files.Glob "config/*").AsConfig | nindent 2 | upper | replace "." "_" }}
```

observe the same issue.

Is it possible to expose the contents of application.properties as key/value pairs in env inside the container?

Comment: can you add an example file from your config/*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the way you are reading your files and configmap configuration.
Assuming your file from *config* folder looks like this (please note that integers should be included in as quoted strings):

**config.ini**

```
SERVER_PORT = "8080" 
SERVER_NAME = LOCALHOST 
SERVER_GREETING = GREETING-SERVICE 
SAMPLE_GROUPA_PARAM1 = VALUE1BASE 
SAMPLE_GROUPA_PARAM2 = VALUE2BASE 
SAMPLE_HIGHERPARAM = VALUEHIGHERBASE
```

**configmap.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: special-config
data:
{{ range $path, $bytes := .Files.Glob "config/*" }}
  {{- $.Files.Get $path | indent 2 | upper | replace "." "_" | replace " = " ": " }}
{{- end }}
```

**pod.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test-pod
spec:
  containers:
    - name: test-container
      image: k8s.gcr.io/busybox
      command: [ "/bin/sh", "-c", "env" ]
      envFrom:
      - configMapRef:
          name: special-config
```

**output:**

```
$ kubectl logs test-pod
KUBERNETES_PORT=tcp://10.96.0.1:443
KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT=443
SAMPLE_GROUPA_PARAM1=VALUE1BASE
SAMPLE_GROUPA_PARAM2=VALUE2BASE
HOSTNAME=test-pod
...
PWD=/
KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST=10.96.0.1
SERVER_GREETING=GREETING-SERVICE
SERVER_PORT=8080
SERVER_NAME=LOCALHOST
```

See [Configure all key-value pairs in a ConfigMap as container environment variables](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#configure-all-key-value-pairs-in-a-configmap-as-container-environment-variables)

Comment: It does go through all the files

Comment: Is it possible to specify hierarchy order of the files that exists in the config dir? example, first application-test.properties should be loaded, then application-dev.properties, then application.properties.

Comment: do you have inputs to specify hierarchy order of the files?

Comment: files are being sort by lexical order

Comment: Cant we specify our custom order?

Comment: no, but you can rewrite the logic and use something like `sort`